# Celsius conversion tabel program

Tags: c++

Celsius Temperature Table in C++

C = 5/9 (F-32)

Write a function named Celsius that accepts a Fahrenheit temperature as an argument. The function named Celsius that accepts a Fahrenheit temperature as an argument. The function should return the temperature, converted to Celsius. Demonstrate the function by calling it in a loop that displays a table of Fahrenheit temperature 0 through 20 and their Celsius equivalents.

I know I am close to finishing this program, but I seem to mixing up/missing my variables. It should print out a two columned table with the temp conversion from 0-20 increasing by 5 each time. Any help would be great! Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Create prototype
double celsius(double);
int main()
{
    double cTemp;

    for(int temp = 0; temp <= 20; temp+= 5)
    {
    double celTemp;
    //Call the function
    celTemp = celsius(temp);
    cout << "The temperature in celsius is: " << temp << setw(6) << 
    cTemp << endl;
    }
}
double celsius(double farenheit)
{
    double cTemp;
    cTemp = 5.0 /9.0 * (farenheit - 32);
    return cTemp;
}
```

Comment: Please describe the specific problem that you are having with your current code.

Comment: Don't forget `argv` exists and it's a lot less messy than 1980s style "DO YOU WANT TO PLAY A GAME? [Y/N]" type prompts.

Comment: Now  with the changed code why does the variable `cTemp;` exist in `main()`? You don't ever give it a value but you try output it. Maybe you wanted to delete `double cTemp;` and output `celTemp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What purpose does `cTemp` serve? I can see in your code that you do not give it any value whatsoever but you are still trying to take its output.

Instead of that, you should remove `double cTemp` and output `celTemp` instead. Since that is the variable you are using to refer the temperature in celsius as obtained from your function.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in my PC. I got all the celsius column values 0. I think your question might be why all that values zero. 
I found a mistake in the for loop while printing the values.
You wrote cTemp there. I think it would be celTemp.
Now it is not showing all of them zero but the correct value.
Have a glimpse ...

```
for(int temp = 0; temp <= 20; temp+= 5)
{
double celTemp;
//Call the function
celTemp = celsius(temp);
cout << "The temperature in celsius is: " << temp << setw(10) << celTemp << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your

```
    for(int temp = 0; temp <= 20; temp+= 5)
    {
    double celTemp;
    //Call the function
    celTemp = celsius(temp);
    cout << "The temperature in celsius is: " << temp << setw(6) << 
    cTemp << endl;
    }
```

doesn't convert the value read from input. From what you say it's not clear what the program should do, but perhaps the argument to the call of the celsius() function should not be just temp, but something like (temp + cTemp).

The for cycle also ignores the value returned from the celsius() function and always prints the value cTemp (i.e. the value read from stdin) in the second column, that's perhaps another error.

Comment: In the for loop he mistook in printing cTemp instead of celTemp. celsius() is returning value to celTemp. So celTemp should be printed.

Comment: That's what I say in the second paragraph. The question has been edited since I wrote my answer, so the first paragraph doesn't make much sense now.